# If I create a role, and assign it to a user but make changes to the role, do I have to then have to re-grant it to the user?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

I have a role but made changes to it, do I have to grant the role to all the users again or will Oracle automatically do it for me?

The issue is that I have made a change to the role but the role is connected to many users, do I have to regrant it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't have to reassign it.